# angularjs submit form through modal form. modal open as template

Tags: angularjs

my main controller is..

```
app.controller('homeCtrl',function($scope,$modal){
    $scope.openLogin=function(){
        var LoginInstance=$modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
            controller: 'loginCtrl'
        });
    }
});
app.controller('loginCtrl',function($scope, $modalInstance){
    $scope.login_submit = function() {
        alert($scope.email)
    };
});
```

On click of login button my model open as template. model contain form.. how to submit that form. i am trying to alert form value. it show me undefine

Comment: Could you also post what's in `partials/login.html`?